Does $\displaystyle\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \frac1{\mathrm{lcm}(1,2,\dots,n)} < \frac1{\mathrm{lcm}(1,2,\dots,m)}$ for arbitrarily large $m$?
It is easy to show $e$ is irrational by using its series representation
$$e = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}$$
By carefully going through the steps of this proof one can isolate important properties and generalize it for series with similar behavior. Here is what I came up with:

Let $(a_n)_n$ be a sequence of positive integers such that

For all $m\in\mathbb N$ there is $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $m|\mathrm{lcm}(a_0, a_1, \dots, a_n)$.
For arbitrarily large $m\in\mathbb N$ we have $\displaystyle\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty\frac1{a_n}<\frac1{\mathrm{lcm}(a_0,
 a_1, \dots, a_m)}$.

Then $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{a_n}$ is irrational.

The second property suggests the sequence must increase quite rapidly. I wonder how slow can we make it.
In an attempt to test this out I decided to set $a_n:=\mathrm{lcm}(1, 2, \dots, n)$ (of course $a_0=1$). This sequence have the nice property (the factorials also have) that $\mathrm{lcm}(a_0, a_1,\dots,a_m)=a_m$ and, of course, $m|a_m$. It remains to check whether
$$\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \frac1{\mathrm{lcm}(1,2,\dots,n)} < \frac1{\mathrm{lcm}(1,2,\dots,m)}$$
but I couldn't prove or disprove this, so I'm seeking for your help.
I've never seen this series being discussed anywhere before. Have it already been proposed and studied?
Notice if $m+1$ is not a prime power, then $a_m = a_{m+1}$ and the inequality does not hold.

For some reason, Wolfram Alpha thinks the series diverges

This is obviously false as $a_n\ge n(n-1)$. The sequence $a_n$ is A003418 on OEIS and there one further claims $a_n\ge 2^{n-1}$. Besides, a famous trivia result states that
$$\lim\sqrt[n]{\mathrm{lcm}(1, 2, \dots, n)} = e$$
so we expect $a_n$ to be approximately $e^n$ for large $n$. The error of this approximation is related to the Riemann Hypothesis, but I hope this discussion is not necessary for the inequality I'm asking about.

@GregMartin what do you mean?

The series has been studied before, see the edit of my answer.

Denote $L_n := \mathrm{lcm}(1, \ldots, n)$. First, we'll begin with a simple proof for the convergence of $\sum_n \tfrac{1}{L_n}$. Observe that $L_n \geqslant n(n-1)$ for all $n > 1$ since $L_n$ is divisible by both $n$ and $(n-1)$, which are themselves relatively prime. Thus, we have:
$$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{L_n} \leqslant 1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n-1)} = 1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n} \right) = 2$$
Now, we claim that $\sum_{m+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{L_n} < \tfrac{1}{L_m}$ for infinitely $m$. In fact, we claim that it holds true if $m + 1$ is prime. This will in fact also prove convergence. Let $m + 1 = p_k$, where $p_{\ell}$ is the $\ell$th prime:
$$\sum_{n=m+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{L_n} \leqslant \sum_{n=p_k}^{p_{k+1}-1}\frac{1}{p_kL_m} + \sum_{n=p_{k+1}}^{p_{k+2}-1} \frac{1}{p_kp_{k+1}L_m} + \cdots = \sum_{\ell = k}^{\infty} \frac{p_{\ell+1}-p_{\ell}}{(p_k\cdots p_{\ell})L_m}$$
By Bertrand's postulate, we have $p_{\ell+1}-p_{\ell} < p_{\ell}$. Using this inequality:
\begin{align}\sum_{n = m+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{L_n} &< \sum_{\ell = k}^{\infty} \frac{p_{\ell}-1}{p_k\cdots p_{\ell}L_m} = \sum_{\ell = k}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{p_k\cdots p_{\ell-1}L_m} - \frac{1}{p_k\cdots p_{\ell}L_m}\right) = \frac{1}{L_m}\end{align}
as required. Note that the inequality is strict since we have $p_{\ell+1}-p_{\ell} < p_{\ell} - 1$ infinitely often. One can also see the strictness of the inequality using the irrationality of the infinite sum.

Here is a graph of the sign of $$\frac{1}{\text{lcm}(1,2,\ldots,m)}-\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty\frac{1}{\text{lcm}(1,2,\ldots,n)}$$

So if I had to guess I'd say that the function change sings infinitely many times but that the inequality you are trying to prove fails for most of the integers.
Edit: the number $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{\text{lcm}(1,2,\ldots,n)}$ has been studied before, it's known to be irrational, see https://oeis.org/A064859

Can you provide the list of the integers for which the inequality holds?

$1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 36, 40,
42, 46, 48, 52, 58, 60, 66, 70, 72, 78, 80, 82, 88, 96, 100,\ldots$

Unfortunately 100 is too small a number to provide any reliable guidance at all as to which side might be more frequent. Keep in mind that between 2 and 100 half of all odd numbers are prime(!). Even $m=10^6$ could easily be too small, but it's at least likely to give somewhat better intuition.

So the first $m$ for which $m+1$ is a prime power and the inequality fails is $m = 31$.
